# SQL server - Aggregate each column with pre-specified aggregation functions - DYNAMICALLY

Tags: sql, azure, dynamic, multiple-columns, aggregate-functions

I have a pretty simple table with an ID, Date, and 20 value columns. Each column and each row can hold different type of data - with different unit of measure - and the ID column defines each fields unit of measure. So basically the ID field helps identifying the meaning behind each fields. Naturally I have an explanatory table that holds these definitions by ID.

The table holds sensor data, and these sensors are inserting thousands of rows of data each second (each TYPE of sensor has their own ID).

My problem is: how to aggregate this kind of table? Because each type of measurement requires different aggregation (some measuremants I need to average, other to sum or min or max etc...).

I think the perfect solution would be something like having an explanatory table by ID, which defines for each field (of that ID) that how should I aggregate them, and the aggregation command (somehow... magically...) should be dynamic by this table...

Do you have any suggestion how I can accomplish that? Or is it even possible to make the aggregation function dynamic by a certain condition (in this case the explanatory tables value)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure SQL is the right tool for the job? sounds to me you want columnar DBs, or other types of noSQL will fit better

Comment: Maybe we should use some other database, but I think the question still stands, whether it is possible to make the aggregate function dynamic or not.

Comment: @eyalkatz . . . The storage mechanism of the data and the relaxation of ACID properties have nothing to do with this question, as I read it.